# How to Scale Parts of an SVG Separately Using Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, css

I am rendering SVGs on a website. There is an SVG I want to use for buttons, but the SVG is a complex design and the website needs to be responsive. Simply scaling the SVG with the viewport can't solve this problem: it distorts the SVG.

Hopefully this illustrates the type of thing I'd like to do, though in reality, my scenario is more complex:

[image]

*By W3C SVG Logo, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=105996438*

As the viewport scales, I want that black overlay, the one between the * and the letters, to scale horizontally, whereas, I want the rest of the SVG to stay the same size.

Can Adobe Illustrator create an SVG that works this way? [I have found an article that describes how to do with SVG *code*](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#aa-how-to-scale-parts-of-an-svg-separately):

> The viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes are incredibly flexible. Once you stop thinking of SVG as just another image format, you can start asking yourself how you want your graphic to scale as the window changes size.
>
> An important thing to realize is that you don’t need to define a single viewBox and preserveAspectRatio option for the entire SVG. Instead, you can use nested  elements, each with their own scaling attributes, to have different parts of your graphic scale independently. (You can also use these attributes on and  elements, and you can use preserveAspectRatio on other images embedded in your SVG.) With this approach, you can create a header graphic that stretches to fill a widescreen display without taking excessive height as well

1. Is this something that *has* to be done by modifying SVG code, or can it be designed in Adobe Illustrator, too?
2. If it can be designed in Adobe Illustrator, how does one test the scaling works correctly in Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want to shrink that black rectangle? If so, this is so easy. Open SVG in Adobe Illustrator. and select the rectangle in layer panel and scale it. or you want that All part of SVG to be responsible? I don't think your scaling method is like to awesome font icons. Try your codes with  awesome font icons first and see is that scaling method appropriate?

Comment: You can edit an SVG in Illustrator. You could increase the size of the rectangle. You seem to be describing some kind of responsive/dynamic scaling, but are you really sure you need that? Seems to me you are trying to overcomplicate things. Why couldn't you just make different buttons of different widths as required?  At the moment your question reads like an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @BillyKerr `You seem to be describing some kind of responsive/dynamic scaling, but are you really sure you need that?` Well, it is for webpage that defines the width of the button as a hundred percent of its parents container. If this were for a gradient or border, I'd say yes, but I don't know if true here. `Why couldn't you just make different buttons of different widths as required?` You mean render different versions? Sure, but if I ever need to modify it, then I need to modify all those versions instead of one.

Comment: @C.F.G I'm not confident, but I don't think that's what I'm saying. The article I linked to shows many examples,  so maybe that can help clarify.

Comment: The problem is that there is no way to control responsive scaling like that inside Illustrator.  So, you have two choices - make different size buttons, or code it. I'm no coder so I can't give you any advice regarding that, and generally coding is off-topic here. I dabble in a bit of hand-coding to edit SVGs, but no expert.  I'm not even sure if it would be possible in pure SVG to be honest, maybe some trick using CSS, but that's only a guess.

Comment: @BillyKerr `The problem is that there is no way to control responsive scaling like that inside Illustrator.` That's not just the problem, it's also the answer to the question ;) I'll accept that if you put it